# What is counting on rate limit of soundcloud?

Tags: limit, soundcloud, rate

In my application I have a search list of musics and an embedded player. I need refactor some functions, but I can't understand what is the specific count event. What is counting in rate limit by SoundCloud? Search for list song is measured? Play calls?

In SoundCloud doc text we have:

"Effective July 1, all requests that result in access to a playable stream are subject to a limit of 15,000 requests per any 24-hour time window".

This refer the all JSON's calls only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A play request is defined as any request against the SoundCloud API which would generate a URL for streaming audio content in its response.

For example, a GET to `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/3/stream` returns a URL which you can use to stream audio content. This request would count against your daily rate limit of play requests.

Hope that helps.